# Representation matrices for transformed structure constants

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $M_i$ with
\begin{equation}  
  [M_i,M_j] = \sum_{k=1}^N f_{i,j,k} \, M_k \qquad i,j=1,\ldots,N
\end{equation}
denote a $d$-dimensional representation of a Lie algebra $\cal{L}$ with structure constants $f_{i,j,k}$.
The structure constants are not unique and $f_{i,j,k}$ may be replaced by
\begin{equation}  
  \tilde{f}_{i,j,k}\equiv\sum_{n,m,s=1}^N A_{i,n}\,A_{j,m}\,(A^{-1})_{s,k}\,f_{n,m,s}
\end{equation}
with an arbitrary, invertible $N{\times}N$ matrix $A$.
I'm looking for a method to construct from $M_i$
the $d$-dimensional representation matrices $\tilde{M}_i$
such that
\begin{equation}  
  [\tilde{M}_i,\tilde{M}_j] = \sum_{k=1}^N \tilde{f}_{i,j,k} \, \tilde{M}_k \qquad i,j=1,\ldots,N
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\tilde{M}_m\equiv \sum_i A_{m,i} M_i$, and further
$$
[\tilde{M}_m,\tilde{M}_n]= \sum_{i,j} A_{m,i} A_{n,j} [M_i,M_j]\\
=  \sum_{i,j,k} A_{m,i} A_{n,j}  f_{i,j,k}  M_k =  \sum_{i,j,k,s,l} A_{m,i} A_{n,j}  f_{i,j,k}  A^{-1}_{k,s}   A_{s,l}   M_l \\
= \sum_{i,j,k,s} A_{m,i} A_{n,j}  f_{i,j,k}  A^{-1}_{k,s}   \tilde M_s  \\ 
=  \sum_{s}  \tilde f_{m,n,s}   \tilde M_s ~~ . 
$$